# Caffe crashes after first iteration?

Tags: machine-learning, ubuntu-14.04, caffe, multi-gpu, pycaffe

Caffe crashes when I train a net.

The [solver](http://pastebin.com/ZbstXD8J) and [model](http://pastebin.com/Ny2bUYHz).

In this case I have only used GPU 0. Here is the error trace:

```
build/tools/caffe train -solver models/mv16f/solver.prototxt -gpu 0

I0113 14:21:05.861361 85242 solver.cpp:289] Learning Rate Policy: step
I0113 14:21:05.862876 85242 solver.cpp:341] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0113 14:21:30.271030 85242 solver.cpp:409]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.00872
I0113 14:21:30.271070 85242 solver.cpp:409]     Test net output #1: loss = 4.62895 (* 1 = 4.62895 loss)
I0113 14:21:32.317018 85242 solver.cpp:237] Iteration 0, loss = 4.62663
I0113 14:21:32.317062 85242 solver.cpp:253]     Train net output #0: loss = 4.62663 (* 1 = 4.62663 loss)
*** Aborted at 1452691298 (unix time) try "date -d @1452691298" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7fe7f65f1cbc caffe::SGDSolver<>::GetLearningRate()
*** SIGFPE (@0x7fe7f65f1cbc) received by PID 85242 (TID 0x7fe7f72057c0) from PID 18446744073548012732; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fe7f49c0d40 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe7f65f1cbc caffe::SGDSolver<>::GetLearningRate()
    @     0x7fe7f65f2281 caffe::SGDSolver<>::ApplyUpdate()
    @     0x7fe7f65d967c caffe::Solver<>::Step()
    @     0x7fe7f65d8990 caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
    @     0x7fe7f673251e caffe::P2PSync<>::run()
    @           0x416aa6 train()
    @           0x418c9a main
    @     0x7fe7f49abec5 (unknown)
    @           0x415819 (unknown)
@                0x0 (unknown)
```

The full output of the train is [here](http://pastebin.com/rkYQA7Df).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solver file has this line

```
lr_policy: "fixed"
```

But the Caffe output has this line

```
lr_policy: "step"
```

If you use stepwise learning, you must define `stepsize`. Again, your solver file indicates that you have defined stepsize, but Caffe output shows no stepsize. Please check your solver file again, and add this line back

```
stepsize: 10000
```

Comment: Thank you It works now.  I should have caught that my mistake.